# Finding files with .java extension in specified folder

Tags: java

Task :

> Write a Java application that accepts two file names as arguments: dirName and fileName Find all non-directory files contained in directory dirName whose name ends in ".java"

I tried to use this code but how can I print out the files ending with ".java" ?
It's the first time I work with this things and I don't know how to use them.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;

public class Filter {

    public static File[] finder(String dirName){
        File dir = new File(dirName);

        return dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() { 
                 public boolean accept(File dir, String filename)
                      { return filename.endsWith(".txt"); }
        });

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String dirName = "src";
        System.out.println(finder(dirName));

    }

}
```

Comment: You seem to be on the right track. Just change `{ return filename.endsWith(".txt"); }` to `{ return filename.endsWith(".java"); }` and you should be ok.

Answer (score 2):

```
return !dir.isDirectory() && filename.endsWith(".java");
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. It works fine now .

```js
import java.io.*;

public class Filter {

  public static File[] finder(String dirName) {
    File dir = new File(dirName);

    return dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
      public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
        return filename.endsWith(".java");
      }
    });
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String dirName = "src";
    File[] files = finder(dirName);
    for (File i: files)
      System.out.println(i.getName());
  }

}
```